# ACR 122U connected with android disconnects immediately while touched tags

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard-reader, acr122

I am using ACR 122U card reader connected with android phone via OTG cable. I tested given code by ACS (http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/5102/ACS-LIB-Android-112-A.zip). The reader connects with phone successfully. But when tags are touched with reader, the reader disconnects immediately. My phone model is Sony M2 Dual. The same code works fine with Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and HTC M8. How can I overcome this problem?